# Why isn't it possible to declare functions with same name in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

Why isn't it possible to declare functions with same name in a UIViewController

[image: Methods with same name in ViewController]

but it is possible to declare functions with the same name in other classes

[image: Methods with same name in other class]

Comment: Please do not paste code images, post your actual code in question

Comment: @donkopotamus because i want show error sign, in code can't show that

Comment: @Jojodmo , i know , but i can declare methods with same name in another class (simple class) please see picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class that it works in is a Swift native class, which supports having function inputs that are differentiated only by their types (with same names).

The other class inherits from `UIViewController`, which means it is bridged to Objective-C, which means it must be able to be called from Objective-C code. Objective-C does NOT allow this functionality, so that is why you have red arrows.

Comment: Is that related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63608385/1436359)?